# Thumbnail previews in Files/Nautilus only show when zoom is 150% or more (18.04)

Tags: nautilus, files, thumbnails

I don't get thumbnail previews in Files (Nautilus) at the default zoom level when using List view.

If I select 150% in the hamburger menu the thumbnails are displayed, and they are displayed in Grid view at all sizes. They are also displayed in the Open File dialog, even though the icon size there is smaller than in Files! They are also displayed in Fedora 27.

Is there a way to force thumbnails to be displayed in Files in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a regression in new version of Nautilus.
I filed a bug on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1769358